# Cyrillic text coming from Document Properties is corrupt in PDF file in docx4j

Tags: java, linux, docx4j, cyrillic

I am trying to convert docx to pdf using docx4j 3.7.7.The issue is pdf is getting generated properly but  the docpropery having cyrillic text is not coming up. It coming as #####. Normal paragraph with cyrillic text is getting generated properly. **The issue is reproducible only in linux.** In windows, docProperty is getting converted properly.
The file for testing can be found here
[file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dsE8XHtXONein-eR88zFAehJceiak1m3)

Below is the code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.docx4j.Docx4J;
import org.docx4j.convert.out.FOSettings;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;

public class TestRussian {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestRussian().convertWordToPdf();

    }

    public void convertWordToPdf() {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =null;
        try {
            File file = new File("Test1.docx");

            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(file);

            boolean checkViaFo = Docx4J.pdfViaFO();
            FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
            fileOutputStream= new FileOutputStream("PDFRussian1.pdf");
            foSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);
            //Getting error in update() during complex field update
            //FieldUpdater updater = new FieldUpdater(wordMLPackage);
            //updater.update(true);

            Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage,fileOutputStream);
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        } finally {
            try {
                if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I have read something about MERGEGORMAT & CHARFORMAT but didnt have much idea on that

Comment: To test in linux, install msfonts in linux machine

Comment: Issue resolve.
I have installed only true type core fonts that has "Andale Mono, Arial, Arial Black, Comic Sans MS, Courier New, Georgia, Impact, Times New Roman, Trebuchet, Verdana, and Webdings fonts". But my docProperty was in Calibri. Tried forcefully changing to Times New Roman in MSWord. During PDF conversion it again changes to Calibri and gettiin ####.

Comment: The issue has 2 solutions: 1. Install claer type fonts using below command : sudo apt-get install cabextract 
mkdir .fonts 
wget -qO- plasmasturm.org/code/vistafonts-installer/vistafonts-installer | bash 
It will install  Constantia, Corbel, Calibri, Cambria, Candara, and Consolas. fonts. 
https://www.pcworld.com/article/2863497/how-to-install-microsoft-fonts-in-linux-office-suites.html

Comment: 2. Map the Calibri fonts to available fonts using FontMapper.
Mapper fontMapper = new IdentityPlusMapper();
PhysicalFont font = PhysicalFonts.get("Times New Roman");
fontMapper.put("Calibri", font);
wordMLPackage.setFontMapper(fontMapper);